# What's the purpose of the :printed keyword in this Clojure doto macro example?

Tags: clojure

I've been looking at this Clojure [doto macro example from ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/doto#example_562), and I can't figure out what the purpose of the `:printed` keyword in the final `println`.

When I enter the example in a REPL, it prints out the HashMap as I would expect, just with a `:printed` displayed after the HashMap:

```
user=> (doto (java.util.HashMap.) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2) (println :printed))
#<HashMap {b=2, a=1}> :printed
{"b" 2, "a" 1}
```

I figured `println` needed a placeholder so that it knows to wait for something coming from the `doto` macro. So I tried seeing what I'd get if I omitted `:printed`:

```
user=> (doto (java.util.HashMap.) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2) (println))
#<HashMap {b=2, a=1}>
{"b" 2, "a" 1}
```

This one prints the same thing, but makes the HashMap without a `:printed` alongside it. Given this result, shouldn't the `doto` example give something like this:

```
#<HashMap {b=2, a=1}>
{"b" 2, "a" 1} :printed
```

What is the `:printed` keyword doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:printed` simply adds " :printed" to the string printed by `println`.
It does not affect the hash-map.

```
(println "Bingo" :printed)
=> Bingo :printed
```